# Quickform2: How to process the form without showing the valid form again?

Tags: php, validation, pear, quickform

Quickform2 has a nice feature. If you use the default renderer you either get the form rendered with the exposed errors if something went wrong during validation or the freezed form if all validation rules couldn't detect any error.

Unfortunatly I couldn't find an example which shows me how I *could dismiss the propagation of the valid form*.

Instead of showing the validated form I would like to send a message which tells the user that everything is ok and the form has been processes.

I think this should be simple!

Thanx in advance

Peter

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer:
the secret lies in

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->validate())  
    ...
```

...in this case it's not necessary to call the renderer!

Peter